# Google Compute Engine Quickstart

Tags: google-compute-engine

this may be dumb, but right off the bat in the quickstart, I am unable to change the machine type to f1-micro like it says.  The drop down shows 1 vcpu and then goes blank when I click on it.  Anyone else having the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Also, what browser and what version are you using?

Comment: Can't speak for DavidGoss, but here's one of my screenshots. Happens in both chromium and firefox: http://imgur.com/UmYb12z

Comment: Same problem here. Please [vote for the bug](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/13243887-fix-buggy-compute-engine-s-new-instance-type-dropd) to be fixed!

Comment: An update has been pushed and this issue should be resolved today by the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

Our engineering team is already aware of this issue and they are working hard to fix it as soon as possible. You can subscribe to [this issue report](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=308) for updates.

With that said, you can use [gcloud command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) to create the instance with your desired machine type.