# Why can't I create micro instances on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I just opened a Google Cloud account, under the 60-day free trial.

I would like to create `f1-micro` [instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types), but I can't see where I can choose this option.

This is how the New Instance page looks like:

[image: Machine type]

(notice the "up to *(?)* cores")

If I click on the dropdown, it's actually empty:

[image: Machine type dropdown]

Now if I click on Customize and try to move the cursors, here is what happens:

[image: Customize]

This all looks very buggy (notice the `NaN`). **Is this because I'm still under the free trial?**

Where am I supposed to find the f1-micro option? Under the dropdown?

Comment: Ow, just noticed that other people are having the [same issue](http://serverfault.com/q/767113/83039). I think I'd better open a bug with Google, but I'm not sure I can contact them without buying a support plan.

Comment: Having the same issue, the dropdown for the instance type is empty

Comment: @LukeP I just [reported the bug](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/13243887-fix-buggy-compute-engine-s-new-instance-type-dropd), please vote for it!

Comment: You can refer to my [answer on this](http://serverfault.com/questions/767113/google-compute-engine-quickstart) post.

Comment: @Faizan Thanks, I've added an answer here as well for anyone stumbling on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported by @Faizan, it's a known issue and Google is working on it:

https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=308

See [his answer on this question](https://serverfault.com/a/767346/83039) for more information.

Comment: I have posted an update on [issue report](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=308)